# Seed std::mt19937 from std::random_device

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Many people seed their Mersenne Twister engines like this:

```
std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());
```

However, this only provides a single `unsigned int`, i.e. 32 bits on most systems, of seed randomness, which seems quite tiny when compared to the 19937 bit state space we want to seed. Indeed, if I find out the first number generated, my PC (Intel i7-4790K) only needs about 10 minutes to search through all 32 bit numbers and find the used seed. (I know that MT is not a cryptographic RNG, but I just did that to get a feel for how small 32 bit really is in these days.)

I am trying to build a function to properly seed a `mt19937` and came up with this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

auto RandomlySeededMersenneTwister () {
    // Magic number 624: The number of unsigned ints the MT uses as state
    std::vector<unsigned int> random_data(624);
    std::random_device source;
    std::generate(begin(random_data), end(random_data), [&](){return source();});
    std::seed_seq seeds(begin(random_data), end(random_data));
    std::mt19937 seededEngine (seeds);
    return seededEngine;
}


int main() {
    auto rng = RandomlySeededMersenneTwister();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << rng() << "\n";    
}
```

This does look like a safe solution to me; however, I have learned that problems with RNG are often times quite subtle.

Provided `std::random_device` produces good, random data on my system, does the code give me a correctly seeded `std::mt19937`?

Comment: As a side note: currently, `std::random_device` does not work correctly on every platform (I'm looking at you MinGW). If you're going the Boost way, then you could use `boost::random_device` instead.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. Well, first off, why do you use a `std::vector` for a comparatively small sequence of known length? A raw array or `std::array` suffice and avoids any dynamic allocation.
2. Next, avoid needless magic numbers. Use `std::mt19937::state_size` instead of manually specifying `624`.
3. Why do you use a lambda? A simple `std::ref(source)` suffices.

The seeding itself looks perfectly fine and there's no actual *error* anywhere in your code.

```
template<class T = std::mt19937, std::size_t N = T::state_size * sizeof(typename T::result_type)>
auto ProperlySeededRandomEngine () -> typename std::enable_if<N, T>::type {
    std::random_device source;
    std::random_device::result_type random_data[(N - 1) / sizeof(source()) + 1];
    std::generate(std::begin(random_data), std::end(random_data), std::ref(source));
    std::seed_seq seeds(std::begin(random_data), std::end(random_data));
    return T(seeds);
}
```

You *could* avoid the need for `random_data` by using counting and transforming iterators as detailed in "*[Sequence iterator? Isn't there one in boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974533/3204551)*".

This is not simpler, but maybe more efficient:

```
template<class T = std::mt19937, std::size_t N = T::state_size * sizeof(typename T::result_type)>
T ProperlySeededRandomEngine () {
    std::random_device source;
    auto make_iter = [&](std::size_t n) {
    return boost::make_transform_iterator(
        boost::counting_iterator<std::size_t>(n), [&](size_t){return source();});
    };
    std::seed_seq seeds(make_iter(0), make_iter((N - 1) / sizeof(source()) + 1));
    return T(seeds);
}
```

[On coliru](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca6ce9c74205e0a5)

If you can upgrade to C++20, use ranges and views ([godbolt](//godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:86,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:86,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:86,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:86,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Crandom%3E%0A%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T+%3D+std::mt19937,+std::size_t+N+%3D+T::state_size+*+sizeof(typename+T::result_type)%3E%0AT+ProperlySeededRandomEngine+()+%7B%0A++++std::random_device+source%3B%0A++++auto+random_data+%3D+std::views::iota(std::size_t(),+(N+-+1)+/+sizeof(source())+%2B+1)%0A++++++++%7C+std::views::transform(%5B%26%5D(auto)%7B+return+source()%3B+%7D)%3B%0A++++std::seed_seq+seeds(std::begin(random_data),+std::end(random_data))%3B%0A++++return+T(seeds)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+x+%3D+ProperlySeededRandomEngine()%3B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+50%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+x()+%3C%3C+%22+%22%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-Wextra%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```
template<class T = std::mt19937, std::size_t N = T::state_size * sizeof(typename T::result_type)>
T ProperlySeededRandomEngine () {
    std::random_device source;
    auto random_data = std::views::iota(std::size_t(), (N - 1) / sizeof(source()) + 1)
        | std::views::transform([&](auto){ return source(); });
    std::seed_seq seeds(std::begin(random_data), std::end(random_data));
    return T(seeds);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I wrote more or less exactly the same function for my own use so of course I think it is pretty awesome. ;-)

Two things that I would do differently (only style, not security):

- Don't hard-code the magic number 624. The [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) `template` `class` has a `static` `constexpr` member `word_size` that you can use instead.  Likewise, instead of `unsigned`, prefer using `result_type`.
- Consider making the function a `template` so it can be used for `std::mt19937_64` (and maybe other compatible engines) as well.

Comment: Does using monospace for `template`, `class`, `static`, and `constexpr` improve the clarity of what you're saying?  If so, you missed `for`, `do`, and `using`.

Comment: @bcrist No, because in the places I used these words, I am using them with their natural language meaning, not to refer to a C++ keyword. If I were talking about a `for` loop or a `using` directive, I would have made that clear by using the appropriate font. Likewise, I would write `int` if I refer to the C++ data type and say “integer” if I refer to the mathematical concept of numbers.

Comment: What I was trying to humorously point out is that *template class*, *static*, and *constexpr* are not just references to C++ keywords, they are natural language concepts in the vocabulary of any competent C++ dev.  It is the concept that's important, not the token that represents it.  Furthermore, in the case of describing `mersenne_twister_engine`, using `class` instead of *class* is actually incorrect.  The standard does not mandate that it (or any other `std` type) use the `class` keyword.  An implementation could just as easily use `struct` if it so desires.

Comment: @bcrist: Kudos for a way to be more precise by getting more colloquial.

Answer (score 10):

I can offer a different possibility of correctly initializing a mt19937 random number generator:

```
auto RandomlySeededMersenneTwister () {
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());
    rng.discard(700000);
    return rng;
}
```

According to this [paper](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/lfsr04.pdf) ("Improved long-period generators based on linear recurrences modulo 2", F. Panneton, P. L'Ecuyer, M. Matsumoto in AVM TOMS Volume 32 Issue 1, March 2006 Pages 1-16), especially figure 4 in chapter 7, one can obtain a mersenne twister state of high quality even when its initialization variables have only a few bits set to a non-zero value. You need to perform about 700000 random number generations (or twists) during/after the initialization phase.

This certainly extends to your case and is much easier to implement. It is, of course, much slower, but random number generator initialization should always only be triggered once in every binary, so this is probably negligible in many cases.

Also, this solution makes it much easier to reproduce results, as it is not needed to save 624 numbers but only one.

Another advantage is the fact, that you can be sure that you get a nice equal distribution. The original solution does not guarantee this property and relies instead on the quality of the source random number generator and its interaction with mt19937.

Comment: Thanks for writing that review.  This was my first thought as well and could be trivially implemented using [`std::discard_block_engine::discard()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discard_block_engine/discard).

Comment: Fortunately, you understood what I meant (`std::mersenne_twister::discard()`) rather than what I wrote!  That takes less than 5 milliseconds on my 64-bit Linux box running a dual-core processor at 2.3GHz.

Comment: :) I didn't even know the `discard_block_engine` class. But reading up on it lead to the above, so thank you! And thank you for the timing information. The Mersenne Twister is really very very fast!

Comment: Burn-in is good, but it does not change the fact that you seed a 624 byte state with just a single integer.

Comment: Well, fact is, that it just does not matter that I only use a single integer. Please refer to the linked paper to understand the background. The assumption that more seeding is better is just plain wrong.

Comment: It does matter. After you seed with a 32 bit int and skip 700k iterations, there is still only 2^32 possible internal states. The paper you are referring to is talking about recovering from a bad internal state, this is not the problem at hand - if you pass a single number to the Mt constructor it uses a seed sequence to fill all its internal state, so you don't start with an almost all zeroes state. But this process (just like discarding) is deterministic, which is the problem the original question is talking about, and discarding does not fix it.

Comment: @etarion You're right in the regard that my answer does not provide means to get around the problem of an attacker searching through all possible seeds to get the same randomizer state. The space the attacker has to search is indeed still very small (he'd need to know the number of discards though, about 20 bits increased space). This seems to mostly be the goal of the question in the first paragraph. In later paragraphs the questioner very broadly switches to a different nomenclature: "proper seed", "correctly seeded". The MT is never advised for safe random numbers.

Comment: @etarion His remark " (I know that MT is not a cryptographic RNG, I just did that to get a feel for how small 32 bit really is in these days.)" also shows that he is not really keen on the safety aspect of his random numbers. And if you are not looking for a safe RNG my solution works just fine (and you can't use a MT anyways...).

Comment: As I said, your "solution" (and what the paper is talking about) is for starting off with a bad internal state. That does not happen when you give a single number to std::mt19937 since it already fills all the state internally using a standard-mandated algorithm (rand.eng.mers in the C++ standard). So it's unclear what you are trying to "solve".

Also, safety is not the only thing where you may want to have more than 32 bits of entropy ... big monte carlo experiments also come to mind.

Comment: @JohanLundberg Just to be clear, MT does not have a 624 byte state, but 624 integer states.

Comment: @drglove, rigth. It's not possible to edit old comments :)

Comment: This code will still never enumerate most of the possible `mt19937` states: it will use `(2^32)` different states or IVs (initialization vectors) at best - which might be fine for some applications, particularly when combined with `discard`. There is, I'm afraid, nothing *correct* about initializing the `mt19937` this way...

Comment: You get good random numbers. Why do random numbers need to enumerate all states?

Comment: @Nils_M This is a pretty interesting and subtle question. I had a statistics textbook with a sequence of random numbers in the appendix. This is a prng with a seed of zero bits, where you just start listing out the "random" numbers in the table starting at the first one. A two state prng is like having two different textbooks, where you flip a coin to decide which textbook to use, which is a seed of one bit. If you want to repeat the same experiment (run the program) many times, you would want as many different textbooks as possible. If you run the program once, using a constant seed is fine.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does *technically* provide you with a 'correctly' seeded `std::mt19937` PRNG. However, the approach is comparatively clumsy - though you're only offering it as example code, to be fair. You can do without explicit magic numbers like `(624)` - for the required `19937` bits.

---

#### header:

```
#include <random>

class X
{
    ...
    mutable std::mt19937 rng; // mutable is a design decision.
    ...

    // thanks to Konrad Rudolph for correcting me on potentially misleading
    // typedefs, that may be misleading with other RNGs.

};
```

#### implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

X::X ()
{
    std::random_device rdev;
    std::seed_seq::result_type data[std::mt19937::state_size];
    std::generate_n(data, std::mt19937::state_size, std::ref(rdev));

    std::seed_seq prng_seed (data, data + std::mt19937::state_size);
    rng.seed(prng_seed);
}
```

The member `X::rng` has a full *random* 19937-bit state ready for use. Of course this will depend on the policy of [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). Not only do you have an essentially inexhaustible period of `(2^19937 - 1)` when using `rng` itself - you also have a random state vector of `19937` bits. The likelihood of re-creating the same initial PRNG state is now ~ (2^-19937), as opposed to (2^-32). Furthermore, *all* **mt19937** states are theoretically reachable with this code.

Comment: I think your code assumes that `std::seed_seq::result_type` == `random_engine::result_type`. This isn’t generally true (e.g. for `std::mt19937_64`). In this code your seed sequence will be generated using 64 `unsigned int`s (= `std::random_device::value_type`), which isn’t sufficient entropy. Am I wrong?

Comment: My point is that your code is intentionally keeping the random engine generic (though short of making it a template parameter) but your seeding code is specific to mt19937. If the specificity is intentional (which is fine), it’s dangerous to hide the connection to a specific RNG behind a generically named typedef.

Comment: That said, I should make it clear that I’m not actually taking issue with your code, my comment was really just a question to confirm my understanding that a 64-bit MT19937 would need to be seeded differently (i.e. with more random bits).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Now I understand your point. You're right. My code looks 'generic', but it is not; and it could be a source of confusion. It might be an 'example', but I don't want anyone using it for 'cargo cult' coding.