# Simple Hangman game in C++

Tags: c++, hangman

I am trying to create a simple Hangman game. The game has an edit mode for first run in which the user has to supply 6 unique words. The game starts by shuffling words, then for every turn, it selects one word that the user has to figure out. The user has only 6 tries to get it right for every word.

How can I improve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include <limits>

namespace
{
    const std::size_t Max = 6;
    const std::regex Letters("^[A-Za-z]+$");
}

std::mt19937 randomEngine()
{
    std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
    thread_local std::random_device source;
    std::generate(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end(), std::ref(source));
    std::seed_seq seeds(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end());
    thread_local std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
    return seeded_engine;
}

template <class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
void copy_if_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count,
               OutputIt result, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    if (count <= 0 || first == last) return;

    if (pred(*first)) *result++ = *first;

    for (Size i = 1; i < count && first != last; ++i)
    {
        if (pred(*first)) *result++ = *++first;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> ask_words()
{
    std::set<std::string> s;
    bool is_good = false;

    while (!is_good)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 6 unique words: ";
        auto begin = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin);
        auto end = std::istream_iterator<std::string>();
        copy_if_n(begin, end,
            Max,
            std::inserter(s, s.begin()),
            [](const auto& str)
        {
            return std::regex_match(str, Letters);
        });

        if (std::cin.fail() || s.size() != Max)
        {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
            if (!s.empty()) s.clear();
            is_good = false;
        }
        else
        {
            is_good = true;
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    return {s.begin(), s.end()};
}

std::string ask_guess(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;
    bool is_good = false;

    while (!is_good)
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << str << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, result);

        if (std::cin.fail() || !std::regex_match(result, Letters))
        {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
            if (!result.empty()) result.clear();
            is_good = false;
        }
        else
        {
            is_good = true;
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    };

    return result;
}

bool askYN(const std::string& str)
{
    char result;
    bool is_good = false;

    while (!is_good)
    {
        std::cout << str << ": ";
        std::cin >> result;
        result = std::toupper(result);

        if (std::cin.fail() || (result != 'Y' && result != 'N'))
        {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";;
            is_good = false;
        }
        else
        {
            is_good = true;
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    };

    return result == 'Y';
}

int main()
{
    // set up game
    auto words = ask_words();
    thread_local auto engine = randomEngine();
    std::shuffle(words.begin(), words.end(), engine);

    // main loop
    do
    {
        // reset game
        auto word(words.back());
        words.pop_back();
        const auto origin(word);
        std::string score(word.size(), '-');
        std::size_t wrong = 0;
        bool running = true;

        // game loop
        while (running)
        {
            const auto guess(ask_guess("Guess a letter or a word"));

            if (guess.length() > 1) // for long word
            {
                if (guess == origin)
                    std::cout << "\n\nThat's right, you win!\n\n";
                else
                    std::cout << "\n\nWrong word\n\n";

                running = false;
            }
            else // for single letter
            {
                bool found = false;
                const auto ch = guess.back();
                for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i)
                {
                    if (word[i] != ch) continue;
                    score[i] = ch;
                    word[i] = '!';
                    found = true;
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    std::cout << "\n\nThat's wrong\n\n";
                    wrong++;
                }
            }

            if (wrong == Max)
            {
                running = false;
                std::cout << "\n\nYou Lose! The word was: " << origin << "\n\n";
            }

            std::cout << score << '\n';
            std::cout << "\n\nThere are " << word.length() << " letters left\n";
            std::cout << "You have " << Max - wrong << " more tries left\n\n";

            if (score == origin)
            {
                running = false;
                std::cout << "\n\nYou win!\n\n";
            }
        };
    }
    while (!words.empty() && askYN("Do you want to play again? [y/n]: "));
}
```

Comment: Do you need to specify std::random_device, std::mt19937 and "engine" as thread_local if you are only using a single thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Confusing use of `thread_local`**

`thread_local` is for variables that can be accessed from multiple threads or have indefinite lifetimes. As you pointed out in your comment, they're implicitly `static`. But in this code:

```
std::mt19937 &randomEngine() 
{
    std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
    thread_local std::random_device source;
    std::generate(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end(), std::ref(source));
    std::seed_seq seeds(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end());
    thread_local std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
    return seeded_engine;
}
```

The other three instructions are always executed, even when they are not needed. And the thread_local variables are used like any other variables which makes one forget that they are `static`.

One way to do things thread local'd (although it's really not needed here, it could all be just `static`) would be:

```
std::mt19937 _helper_randomEngine()
{
    std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
    std::random_device source;
    std::generate(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end(), std::ref(source));
    std::seed_seq seeds(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end());
    std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
    return seeded_engine;
}

std::mt19937 &randomEngine() {
    /* Could even replace _helper_randomEngine by an anonymous lambda,
       avoiding the external declaration of _helper_randomEngine(); */
    thread_local static engine = _helper_randomEngine();
    return engine;
}
```

Here the seeding instructions are only ever called once, and the `std::random_device` is not kept track of as it's unnecessary. The `static` is extraneous but not harmful, it's up to you whether to keep it or not.

**Abuse of `std::`**

This is debatable, but in source files (not headers!) I like doing `using namespace std;`, especially if it's going to be used *a lot* like in your source file.

**Unreadable bits, Overusage of iterators**

This could use some comments:

```
template <class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
void copy_if_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count,
               OutputIt result, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    if (count <= 0 || first == last) return;

    if (pred(*first)) *result++ = *first;

    for (Size i = 1; i < count && first != last; ++i)
    {
        if (pred(*first)) *result++ = *++first;
    }
}
```

but it's basically a function that reads n inputs matching the predicate, and copies them to result.

But the way it's called:

```
    auto begin = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin);
    auto end = std::istream_iterator<std::string>();
    copy_if_n(begin, end,
        Max,
        std::inserter(s, s.begin()),
        [](const auto& str)
    {
        return std::regex_match(str, Letters);
    });
```

It makes the whole thing seems overly complicated and feel like you forced yourself to use `std::copy`.

You could have done it much simpler:

```
do {
   string str;
   cin >> str;

   if (str.length() > 0 && regex_match(str, Letters)) {
       s.insert(str);
   }
} while (s.size() < Max && !cin.fail());
```

This also has the benefit to wait until 6 *different* strings are inputted.

**Duplication of code**

```
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Or

```
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
```

Shows several times. Putting it in an explicit function called `clear_input()` or whatever and calling that function would be better practice.

**Confusing auto calls**

This is debatable, but things like:

```
const auto guess(ask_guess("Guess a letter or a word"));
```

At first read one might think that `guess` is a function. Why not simply:

```
const auto guess = ask_guess("Guess a letter or a word");
```

It's less confusing, and not slower, because of [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). But the `const auto` is weird here, you might as well do `const auto &` and the reference will be kept to a temporary that will continue to exist as long as the reference does:

```
const auto &guess = ask_guess("Guess a letter or a word");
```

**Over complication**

I'm going to take the `ask_guess` function as an example and show the various problems.

```
std::string ask_guess(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;
    bool is_good = false;

    while (!is_good)
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << str << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, result);

        if (std::cin.fail() || !std::regex_match(result, Letters))
        {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
            if (!result.empty()) result.clear();
            is_good = false;
        }
        else
        {
            is_good = true;
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    };

    return result;
}
```

First problem:

```
std::getline(std::cin, result);
```

Why? Input first accepted strings with `>>` in `ask_words`, it's a different behavior here. You're probably doing that so something like "abc def" counts as 1 invalid input and not 2 valid inputs, but if so **add a comment** explaining why.

Otherwise somebody looking at the code will maybe think you made an error and change the code.

That said, you still do afterwards:

```
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
```

So input is cleaned *anyway*.

Then:

```
if (!result.empty()) result.clear();
```

Just do `result.clear();`. But why do it anyway? It's going to be overwritten in the next reading operation.

Finally, you can remove the boolean flag and have this code:

```
std::string ask_guess(const std::string& str)
{
    while(1) {
        std::string result;

        std::cout << '\n' << str << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, result);

        if (cin.fail() || !std::regex_match(result, Letters)) {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
            clear_input();
            continue;
        }

        /* Could do RVO if result was declared & returned outside of the loop but move
         * constructor will be called anyway */
        return result;
    };
}
```

By the way, if something happened to your program that will make `cin` permanently fail, it'll cause an **endless loop**. It's better to throw an exception at the first sign of `cin` failing (especially when reading strings!) and catch it top-level.

I also noticed the lack of `std::endl` or `std::flush`, I wonder if there's any reason why.

---

I didn't analyze the rest of the code, but the summary is that this code feels very academical and not too practical, with some mistakes here and there. At least, it's a lot better than the other extreme (with C-style things everywhere) and you demonstrate knowledge of the different things part of C++.

Comment: thanks for answer, a lot of good points but multi-threads topic is a lot complicated for me, i have posted code in this site earlier but i got different explanations regrading `thread_local` here link to it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114066/simple-random-generator. according to that answer he mentioned that `thread_local` is implies static, is that right.

Comment: @MORTAL that is right, I will edit my answer accordingly. I still have something to say about that piece of code :p

Comment: @coyotte508 In the rewritten `ask_guess` is there an issue with not checking cin for `eof` or `bad`? Perhaps `!cin.good()` is more defensive?

Comment: @cmh `cin.fail()` will detect errors or end of file, so I'm probably not understanding where the problem is.

Comment: @coyotte508 my reading of [this doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is that when eofbit is set, but badbit and failbit are not set, then `.eof()` will return true, but `.fail()` will return false. Perhaps I'm misreading the docs.

Comment: @cmh, well, `!cin.good()` will return true even if end of file is reached *after* reading, `cin.fail()` would return false then (or true if eof is reached *before* reading, as then it would have failed reading inputs). So `cin.fail()` is correct, if we give to the program a file as input with the last guess being the correct one, `!cin.good()` would discard the guess while `cin.fail()` wouldn't. But yea if eof is reached without a valid guess anyway, as said in the answer, there will be an endless loop.