# Guess the number with a twist

Tags: c++, number-guessing-game

I wrote a program where the *computer* guesses a random number.

To do this, I implemented a form of binary search. This correctly handles any edge-cases that I know of, including `0` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. This doesn't handle negative numbers (since `rand` will never return one) but that could easily be fixed.

The average amount of tries it takes to guess the number is around 29 or 30.

Here it is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <ctime>

static int random_number;

int compare(int guess)
{
    if(guess > random_number)
        return 1;
    if(guess < random_number)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

struct guess_stats
{
    int guesses = 0;
    int number = 0;
};

guess_stats finder(std::function<int(int)> &&cmp)
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int min = 0;
    int guess = (min + max) / 2;
    int cmp_result;
    guess_stats results;

    do
    {
        cmp_result = cmp(guess);

        if(cmp_result < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Greater than " << guess;
            min = guess;
            const int diff = max - guess;
            guess += diff - (diff / 2);
        }
        else if(cmp_result > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Less than " << guess;
            max = guess;
            const int diff = guess - min;
            guess -= diff - (diff / 2);
        }

        std::cout << '\n';

        results.guesses++;
    } while(cmp_result);

    results.number = guess;

    return results;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    random_number = std::rand();
    guess_stats stats = finder(compare);

    std::cout << "Number: " << stats.number << '\n'
              << "Guesses: " << stats.guesses << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm looking for:

- Although I don't expect there will be, are there any edge-cases I may not have seen?
- Are there any algorithmic changes that I could make to have less time-complexity? I don't think so (because this is only `O(log n)` as it is), but I may be surprised to find out.
- Are there any better ways to generate random numbers? I used `srand`, `time`, and `rand` in this program, but those are old solutions. I imagine C++ has something much more up-to-date for generation of random numbers.
- Any other general advice on what to improve would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

## Non-const static variables

Your code shows a lot of good practices:

- variables are always initialized when possible
- variables have proper names (and you stuck to a single naming scheme)
- no unecessary `std::endl`

However, there is one drawback:

```c
static int random_number;
```

That line right there is, at least from my point of view, a flaw. `static` variables are a nice escape hatch in some circumstances, but here it's unnecessary. We can easily use another argument to `finder`, for example:

```cpp
guess_stats finder(comparison_function && cmp, int random_number) {
   ...
}
```

Or we could combine the comparison function with the number to be guessed in a struct, similar to `guess_stats`.

Either variant makes sure that our changes in `finder` won't spill into the rest of our program flow. While we don't intend to change `random_number` in `finder`, it's easy to accidentally write `random_number++` or press `<Tab>` in an IDE with the wrong completion. If we were to use multiple `finder` variants in separate threads, we would have a hard time to debug the behaviour, especially if there is more than a single `static` variable.

However, I guess you've used `random_number` as a static variable to ease the use of `compare`. There are other ways that we will inspect at the end of this review.

Note that `const static` or `constexpr static` variables on the other hand are fine, as they cannot lead to debugging troubles (unless you `const_cast` them, but at that point we're deep within undefined behaviour territory).

## Q&A

> Although I don't expect there will be, are there any edge-cases I may not have seen?

What happens if I use the following comparison?

```cpp
int compare(int unused) {
    return 1;
}
```

Sure, that's not a valid comparison, however, there is nothing in `finder` that blocks us from using such a function. Given that a binary search should take at most \$\log_2(n)+1\$ steps, we can introduce a simple limit of 33 iterations.

> Are there any algorithmic changes that I could make to have less time-complexity? I don't think so (because this is only O(log n) as it is), but I may be surprised to find out.

That's all correct, and from an \$\mathcal O\$ analysis there's nothing to improve.

> Are there any better ways to generate random numbers?

There's the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header. We can use the example code from [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to generate a random number:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    const int random_number = dist(gen);

    ...
}
```

However, keep in mind that this usually won't seed a `mt19937` correctly and [there are ways around that issue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device).

## Getting rid of `random_number`

Given that we use `<functional>`, we use at least C++11. Therefore, we have lambdas at hand. We can use this to our advantage to get rid of `random_number` in `main`:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    const int random_number = dist(gen);

    auto compare = [random_number](int guess) {
        if (guess > random_number) {
            return 1;
        } else if (guess < random_number) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;  
    };

    guess_stats stats = finder(compare);
    ...
}
```

We don't even need to change `finder` to use the new comparison, thanks to `std::function<int(int)>&&`.

Comment: Nice use of a lambda. Hadn't thought about that.